# How do I remove unwanted spaces from the 6 digit page number in Reference?

Tags: bibtex

To cite a paper, I am using the following code in my .bib file:

```
@article{...,
  title={...},
  author={... and ... and ...},
  journal=IEEE_O_ACC,
  volume={1},
  pages={123456--123469},
  month=jan,
  year={2019},
}
```

In the output paper, the page numbers appear as follows:

> ~~~, ~~~, and ~~~, "~~~," *IEEE Access*, vol. 1, pp. 123 456-123 469, Jan. 2019.

I want to change the above one as follows:

> ~~~~~~~ pp. 123456-123469, ~~~~~~.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't give us enough information to help.  This is not the behavior of some of the simple bibliography styles.  So what bibliography style are you using?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry for giving not enough information. I am using the documentclass as `\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}` and bibtex style as `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` and `\bibliography{IEEEabrv,myBib}`. The manual bibtex file is the file, myBib.bib.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include those particular details in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I just break up the numbers into 3-digit groups, or insert a `\relax` between the 3-digit groups.

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{junk.bib}
@article{abc,
  title={...},
  author={... and ... and ...},
  journal=IEEE_O_ACC,
  volume={1},
  pages={{123}{456}--123\relax469},
  month=jan,
  year={2019},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
Cite\cite{abc}

\bibliography{junk}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a simple and good way!!!! By the way, what is different between to break up the numbers into 3-digit groups and to use `\relax`?

Comment: @Danny_Kim Choose whichever way feels more natural...both techniques break up the 6 digits, thus fooling the underlying bib style of `IEEEtran`.